# modify existing where condition in sql expression

Tags: c#, mysql, ormlite-servicestack

Given this Sql Expression as an **input** parameter: (assume there's no way to modify how this input parameter is generated)

```
Db.From<Contact>().Where(C => C.Email != null).Or(C => C.Reference != null);
```

The method needs to append another condition, e.g.

```
exp.And(C.UserId == Session.UserId);
```

However the UserId condition must be true regardless of any existing conditions. But since the original Sql Expression uses "Or" the UserId condition is not enforced.

So the final Sql should look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Contact WHERE (Email IS NOT NULL OR Reference IS NOT NULL) AND UserId == 12
```

At the moment the Sql generated looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM Contact WHERE Email IS NOT NULL OR Reference IS NOT NULL AND UserId == 12
```

Any one have any ideas?

EDIT:
So far the only thing that works is to hack the WhereExpression to add ( ) before and after the Where clause of the original Sql Expression. Just hoping there would be a nicer way.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Where(C => C.UserId == Session.UserId)
```

Comment: This seems to behave the same as the "And" and so the "Or" condition from the original Sql Expression will override any conditions defined here.

Comment: @vonec hmmm, that sounds like a bug in the sql generator; a `Where` should apply to the entire `IQueryable<T>`

Comment: @vonec in that case, you would have to rebuild the `Expression` tree (perhaps via `ExpressionVisitor`); is the `.Expression` available on the object?

Comment: I'm using ServiceStack OrmLite, if that helps. Are you saying then having ```.Where(condition1).Or(condition2).And(condition3);``` means condition1 must always be true? Doesn't seem right to me...

Comment: @vonec I didn't say anything whatsoever about `And`. I used `Where`, for a reason.

Comment: I updated the OP with an Edit and so far the only way I can think of is to "hack" the WhereExpression string and add the parentheses in the original where clause before adding my condition.

Comment: @vonec well as I said: if the `.Expression` is available, you could use `ExpressionVisitor` to tweak it and re-apply to the base data

Comment: I dont how ormlite generates the query from linq. But maybe an approach like this could work. 
Db.From<Contact>().Where(C => C.Email != null || C.Reference != null).And(C.UserId == Session.UserId);